# Redis issue with magento

Tags: magento

Can anyone help me... I have magento website running with nginx and php-fpm. I have configured 2 instance of redis for magento. 
but I'm getting following errors.

Magento reports

```
####################################################
a:4:{i:0;s:24:"read error on connection";i:1;s:2003:"#0 <doc_root>/lib/Credis/Client.php(440): Credis_Client->__call('select', Array)
####################################################
```

and in nginx error log

> 2016/04/29 05:58:44 [error] 5941#0: *829068 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: , server: www.mysite.com, request: "POST /index.php/api/index/index/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.mysite.com"

Please provide me fix on this I have also tried by increasing read timeout value in local.xml to 30 but still getting this error.

Comment: Can you specify your magento version?

Answer (score 0):

What os are you running? In my case i use Debian wheezy and i need to make shure i have the package "php5-redis" installed. This is to make redis talk with php fpm natively with credis library. If you do not know how to install this package, in local.xml change `<force_standalone>0</force_standalone>` to `<force_standalone>1</force_standalone>` to use php (slower) instead of credis

Comment: It is redhat 6.7 , as you mentioned option <force_standalone>0</force_standalone> is already present in my local.xml
php redis module is also installed....is there any way to solve this?

Comment: I told you to switch to '1' and not to '0'..read again my answer :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.
can you explain what it does?

Comment: Collin Mollenhour is the writer of the Magento Redis cache backend module. Please take a look at his git repo here https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis. As per his description , 0 for phpredis, 1 for standalone PHP . So you are having hard time installing redis extension for php (for better speed), then just use the native php installed (lower speed but at least it's working)

Comment: Is there any other option that can be a solution except these points?